# Show value if customer logged in and customer email is X

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, custom, if

I want to show a value on the product page that only an Admin can see.

What is the best way to do this?

I was thinking of an `if` statement that checks if I am logged in and also checks my email.

It would be easier if it knew I was logged into the Backend though as I wouldnt have to log in as a customer.

Thanks

Comment: First of all Admin can become for backend only.You are  using worong Admin  for frontend.You may need to ask how to show  information for specific type of Customers on product page.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Customer group instead and used the following code:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
      $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
      $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);

if($group->getCode()=="New-Customer-Group"){
// Custom Code 
}
}
```